# Android app restart when click on app icon

Tags: android

When i install android app ,on installation complete there are two options ,'Done' and 'Open'
if i choose open to run installed app, and then press home button and click on app icon (First time click on app icon) then splash activity is opened while app is already running.The problem is , I wants not to call splash activity if app running already.

Comment: Share your manifest...i guess launchMode are not set properly for activities.